# Nodejs Passport req.user undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, passport.js

When im logging in the req.user but i gone `undefined` and `req.isAuthenticated()` is `False`. Maybe I'm doing something wrong, I ran out of ideas.

Also deserializeUser is never called, instead serializeUser still working well.
I also check all other issue, almost of them just rearranged the position of bodyParser and cookieParser but it's not work with my issue.

```
app.js

var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var cors = require('cors')
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
var session = require('express-session');
var passport = require('passport');
var passportconfig = require('./config/passport')(passport);
var flash = require('connect-flash');

// var index = require('./routes/index');
var wallet = require('./routes/api/walletAPI');
var index = require('./routes/index');

var app = express();
//mongoose connection
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/wallet');
var dbMongo = mongoose.connection;
dbMongo.on('err', console.error.bind(console, 'connect fail'));
dbMongo.once('open', function () {
    console.log('mongo connected');
});

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'hbs');

app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', req.headers.origin);
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With, X-HTTP-Method-Override, Content-Type, Accept');
    if ('OPTIONS' == req.method) {
        res.send(200);
    } else {
        next();
    }
});
//Enable All CORS Requests
// app.use(cors({credentials: true}));

app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(cookieParser());
const cookieExpirationDate = new Date();
const cookieExpirationDays = 365;
cookieExpirationDate.setDate(cookieExpirationDate.getDate() + cookieExpirationDays);
app.use(session({secret: 'keyboard cat', saveUninitialized: true, resave: true, cookie: {
    secure: false,
    httpOnly: true,
    expires: cookieExpirationDate // use expires instead of maxAge
}}));
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
    console.log(err);
});
app.use(flash());

// app.use('/', index);
app.use('/wallet/api', wallet);
app.use('/', index);

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    var err = new Error('Not Found');
    err.status = 404;
    next(err);
});


// Session-persisted message middleware
app.use(function(req, res, next){
    var err = req.session.error,
        msg = req.session.notice,
        success = req.session.success;

    delete req.session.error;
    delete req.session.success;
    delete req.session.notice;

    if (err) res.locals.error = err;
    if (msg) res.locals.notice = msg;
    if (success) res.locals.success = success;

    next();
});

// error handler
app.use(function (err, req, res, next) {
    // set locals, only providing error in development
    res.locals.message = err.message;
    res.locals.error = req.app.get('env') === 'development' ? err : {};

    // render the error page
    res.status(err.status || 500);
    res.render('error');
});

module.exports = app;
```

walletAPI.js

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var walletController = require('../../controller/walletController');

router.post('/login', function (req, res, next) {
    var result = walletController.log_in(req, res, next);
    req.session.save();
})
```

walletController.js

```
var history = require('../models/history');
var wallet = require('../models/wallet');
var md5 = require('md5');
var passport = require('passport');

exports.log_in = passport.authenticate('local-signin', {
    successRedirect: '/a',
    failureRedirect: '/login',
    failureFlash: 'Invalid username or password.',
    successFlash: 'Success.'
});
```

passport.js

```
var LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;
var User = require('../models/wallet');
var md5 = require('md5');

module.exports = function(passport){
    //Passport configuration
    passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
        console.log('user:')
        console.log(user._id)
        done(null, user._id);
    });

    passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
        console.log('id:')
        console.log(id)
        User.findById(id, function(err, user) {
            done(err, user);
        });
        done(null, id);
    });

    passport.use('local-signin',new LocalStrategy({
            usernameField : 'username',
            passwordField : 'password',
            passReqToCallback: true,
        },
        function(req, username, password, done) {
            process.nextTick(function () {
                User.findOne({'username': username}, function (err, user) {
                    // console.log(user)
                    if (err) {
                        return done(err);
                    }
                    if (!user) {
                        return done(null, false, req.flash('loginMessage', 'No user found.'));
                    }
                    else if (user.password !== md5(password)) {
                        return done(null, false, req.flash('loginMessage', 'Oops! Wrong password.'));
                    }
                    return done(null, user);
                });
            })
        }
    ));
}
```

Comment: Can you provide the line where the error come from

Comment: there is no error, req.user just be undefined after the client login